# Opening index.html without running localserver in webpack dist folder

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, electron

I have created the output files/folder after webpack build. The index.html has been generated in dist folder with scripts and styles folder.

The configuration in package.json is as follow

```
"build": "rimraf dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --colors",
```

But when I open index.html it is simply showing a blank page. It works only after running in local server. As I want to run it through electron desktop app, I want it to run as a standalone without starting any server.

UPDATE:
here is how I am opening the electron window

[image]